# curl https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip returns nothing

Tags: python, macos, curl

I have run into a very strange error on my MacBook. I've seen some similar posts but none of them solved my issue.

I've been trying to install some Python libraries, and I tried to use curl to view this link: https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/

It's very strange that the curl command returned nothing but a bash prompt like:

```
$ curl https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip

$
```

At the beginning, I thought that's my proxy/firewall's problem, but when I try the link in my Safari/Chrome, the web browser displays the page perfectly.

What's wrong with my curl command? I am using curl coming alone with Mac OS El Capitan.

```
$ which curl
/usr/bin/curl
```

Comment: Pip comes pre-installed on the latest Pythons, so is that link just an example?

Answer (score 2):

Try using curl in verbose mode to see why:

```
curl -v https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip
```

The response is a permanent redirect. It works if you append a trailing slash as follows:

```
curl https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
```